# How to handle "Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging" Error

Tags: sonarqube

We've suddenly got the SonarQube Error on CI/CD pipeline, Concourse. Since we had no change around sonar properties recently, totally confused what this error requires us.

```
Preparing SonarQube scanner...
Starting sonar-scanner (type: cli)...
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /tmp/build/put/sonar-input/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.0.0.1744
INFO: Java 1.8.0_151 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.15.0-159-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: SonarQube server 7.9.1
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11+ to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=70ms
～
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=14ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=4ms
INFO: Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer
INFO: Sensor Java CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=81ms
INFO: 55 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 44 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 91ms, dir size=696 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 319ms, zip size=316 KB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 18.928s
INFO: Final Memory: 32M/995M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: The 'report' parameter is missing
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR in /opt/resource/out : line 251 with exit code 2
```

Is there any way to handle this error...?
And just wondering it would be clear this issue if we would reboot the sonarqube docker.
Any adivise would be highly appreciated.

```
docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
    968xxxxxxx5b        bitnami/sonarqube:7.9.1   "/app-entrypoint.sh …"   9 months ago        Up 8 months         0.0.0.0:80->9000/tcp             docker_sonarqube_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to following discussion, we understood that caused by the lack of disk spaces. After clean-up, it worked fine in our case.

```
Error: The ‘report’ parameter is missing
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-the-report-parameter-is-missing/9616
– Faced similar issue, and found disk space issue on the server. Once clearing the disk space it worked.

Sonarqube : The 'report' parameter is missing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805695/sonarqube-the-report-parameter-is-missing
--I just had the same problem here: my Linux server ran out of disk space and Sonarqube started to produce the report parameter is missing error. After deleting some unused files and restarting sonarqube, everything worked normal again
```